# How do I get the trackback count of a post in wordpress without writing an SQL query?

Tags: theme-development, themes, templates, template-tags, pingbacks

How do I get the trackback count of a post in wordpress without writing an SQL query?

I tried searching [Brave Search](https://search.brave.com) and I couldn't find anything helpful. To fetch the amount of comments a post has, [`get_comments_number()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments_number) is the wordpress protocol function for it. But what if I want to fetch the amount of trackbacks a post has?

And also, do I have to be inside "the loop" to do this? What if I'm outside the loop?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify what kind of comment you want to retrieve using [`get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments).

```
// Assumes you've set $post_id somewhere.
$args = array(
    'type' => 'trackback',
    'post_id' => $post_id,
);
$trackbacks = get_comments( $args );
$trackback_count = count( $trackbacks );
```

**Edited to add:** As [Sally CJ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/137402/sally-cj) points out in the comments, you can do this in just one step:

```
// Assumes you've set $post_id somewhere.
$args = array(
    'type'    => 'trackback',
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    'count'   => true,
);
$trackback_count = get_comments( $args );
```

This code is **untested** but it should provide you a starting place.

As far as being inside/outside The Loop: The above code should work just fine either way, as long as you've got a way to get the post ID (`get_the_ID()` should work in The Loop; if you've got a `WP_Post` object called `$my_post`, then `$my_post->ID` should get it for you).

### References

- [`get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments)
- [Allowed comment query arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/)

Comment: , but the `count` argument can be used to get only the total number of trackbacks/comments, e.g. `$trackback_count = get_comments( array( 'type' => 'trackback', 'post_id' => $post_id, 'count' => true ) );` ..

Comment: Good point, I've added that to the answer. Thanks!